# Rails when I wrap a table with a form the table disappears checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am not sure what is happening here. When I wrap the form around the table the table disappears. When I remove the form, the table reappears. Thanks in advance. Here is the code:

```
<% form_tag deposit_checks_path :method => :put do %>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Checkbox</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Mailer ID</th>
          <th>Payment amt</th>
          <th>Transaction type</th>
          <th>Transaction</th>
          <th>Deposit</th>
          <th>User</th>
          <th colspan="3"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>

        <% @payments.each do |payment| %>
          <tr>
            <td><%= check_box_tag "payment_id[]", payment.id, checked = false %></td>
            <td><%= payment.created_at %></td>
            <td><%= payment.mailer_id %></td>
            <td><%= number_to_currency(payment.payment_amt) %></td>
            <td><%= payment.transaction_type %></td>
            <td><%= payment.transaction_id %></td>
            <td><%= payment.deposit_id %></td>
            <td><%= payment.user_id %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', payment %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_payment_path(payment) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', payment, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
           <% end %>
           </tbody>
    </table>
<%= submit_tag "Edit Checked" %>
<% end %>
```

thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you notice in your code?

```
<% form_tag deposit_checks_path :method => :put do %>
```

you forgot to add a `comma`. It should have been

```
<% form_tag deposit_checks_path, :method => :put do %>
```

otherwise the `method: :put` is appended to the `action` attribute
[image]

Main Point:

> You forgot to put an equals sign before `form_tag`

Try this

```
<%= form_tag deposit_checks_path, :method => :put do %>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I did a copy and paste and didn't check it close enough. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Checkbox</th>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Mailer ID</th>
    ..
    ..
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <% form_tag deposit_checks_path :method => :put do %>

        <table>
           <% @payments.each do |payment| %>
          <tr>
             <td><%= check_box_tag "payment_id[]", payment.id, checked = false %></td>
            <td><%= payment.created_at %></td>
            <td><%= payment.mailer_id %></td>
            ...
            ...

          </tr>
          <%end%>
        </table>
      <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```